# Rendering Angstrom in R Markdown

Tags: latex, knitr, mathjax, r-markdown

I want to make the angstrom symbol in my r markdown document. Normally in latex you can just do `\AA` for the angstrom symbol. However, I am trying the simple `$\AA$` in my `r` markdown file and it is not rendering. I have tried `\AA{}, \Aa, \aa`, and

```
$$  
\AA  
$$
```

as well with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF8 has the angstrom, the font is problematic though.
Another approach is to use `overset`.

These are not perfect as LaTeX, but still acceptable (at least for me).

```
$$1Å=10^{−10}m$$
$$1\overset{\circ}{A}=10^{-10}m$$
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The **rmarkdown** package uses Pandoc, which in turn uses MathJax, to render math expressions in HTML. It is known that `\AA` does not work in MathJax (at least at this moment); see its issue [#795](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/795), and you will also see alternative approaches there.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Unicode for angstrom, but you have to convert to decimal from hex. The hex for angstrom is 212B, so this is 8491 in decimal. Thus  &#8491 will work

Answer (score 0):

You could inline unicode into R Markdown using `asis_output` :

```
# Inlined unicode - Angstrom : `r knitr::asis_output('\U212B')`
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I develop it to fit this

$\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{C}}$